# SQL to java 2d matrix

Tags: java, sql

I don't understand why it's closing the connection and not giving me the info from the resultset in to the `int[][]` someone could help me i'm stuck thanks

```
public void InsertBoredFromSQL()
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    int[][] Arr = new int[8][8];
    String Query = "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H from Games where GameID =" + this.res;
    //this is a variable to help from the outside (globale) 

    try
    {
        //crate connection
        conn = getConnection();
        //crate statement and execute query
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs1 = st.executeQuery(Query);
        //from here it jumps to the exeption and i don't know why it wont run
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                rs1.next();
                char c = 'A';
                char column = (char) (i + c);
                Arr[i][j] = rs1.getInt(column);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.

Comment: Missing rs1.next()  ?

Comment: Look at how to use the ResultSet  class. You don't need to call first. You are already at the first record.

Comment: Yes, you need to use a `rs1.next()` to read the first row.

Comment: where that's my dilemma

Comment: Also, your select gets only 8 columns, but you are trying to read 64 columns.

Comment: Yeah, don't do `rs1.first()` - that's the part that's not supported.  And you need `rs1.next()` before you start reading the data.

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row. thats after i aded the rs1.next();

Comment: So does your SQL actually return any rows?

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 65 is out of range.or this one depends one where i put the rs1.next();

Comment: how am i fixing the 65 index it shuldn't get there

Comment: The reason for the 65 is that you're using a `char` instead of a `String` for your column name.  You can pass either a `String` or an `int` to `getInt` and get the result you expect.  But if you pass `char`, it will get converted to `int`, which isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Part of you problem is this:

```
 char c = 'A';
 char column = (char) (i + c);
 Arr[i][j] = rs1.getInt(column);
```

Here you are using the method [`ResultSet#getInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)), There is no method that takes a `char` as an argument, so the `char` is converted to an `int` which in your case for the first iteration is `A` which is  `65`

Either use the index starting at 1 to get the first column of the result set, or convert the column char into a string to get the column by name.

You might also be better off using a while loop for your result set - consider what would happen if your query returned the unexpected number of rows. You can do this like so:

```
while(rs.next())
{
    // Do your row operations
}
```

This works as [`ResultSet#next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) will advance to the next row and also return true or false based on if there are further rows.

This also brings up another issue with your code - your `rs.next()` call is within your inner loop - this means you will advance a row and column for each iteration and are then likely to get a new exception.

Also you can get better details from exceptions if you use

```
catch(Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace()
}
```